# pci-stub not claiming radeon card, only the audio device, radeon driver claiming graphics instead

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati, radeon

im trying to bind my spare radeon card to pci-stub on kubuntu 15.04, ive got this for my boot options

dmesg | grep pci-stub

> [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.19.0-15-generic root=/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash pci-stub.ids=1002:6779,1002:aa98 vt.handoff=7

but later on in the output i get this

> [    4.349476] pci-stub: add 1002:6779 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
>
> [    4.349485] pci-stub: add 1002:AA98 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
>
> [    4.349504] pci-stub 0000:02:00.1: claimed by stub

i grepped for radeon in my dmesg output, and indeed its only claiming the sound output device and radeons taking the graphics device, anyone know what the hell is going on?

lspci | Radeon

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X]
>
> 01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]
>
> 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
>
> 02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]

lspci -n | grep 02:00.

> 02:00.0 0300: 1002:6779
>
> 02:00.1 0403: 1002:aa98

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Happens the same on my machine.

Comment: sadly no, i cant find any information on how to actually go about fixing it, although in fedora you can use dracut to load pci-stub before radeon by making radeon depend on pci-stub. dracut is available in ubuntu, but when i tried installing it it threatened to uninstall a bunch of stuff that id really rather not be without.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the `radeon` module is taking control of the device before pci-stub, so you need to reverse the load order.

Blacklist the `radeon` module:

```
$ echo blacklist radeon | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And add the module to initramfs:

```
$ echo radeon | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

After, reboot. Problem solved!

Comment: ive got 2 AMD cards, and one of them needs to go to ubuntu, so blacklisting radeon isnt an option. as i mentioned above, dracut seems to be the answer to my problems, but it means ditching ubuntu, and thats a pain.

Comment: I have two AMD cards too, but it works; blacklisting a module doesn't mean that the module can't be loaded at all - it means that it's not loaded automatically. The `initrafms` addition will load it.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.  Also, is `update update-initramfs` a typo?

Comment: If you refer to the `update`, yes, it was a typo! Thanks, I've fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

My fix to this was the steps indicated by Marcus but with the following changes:

Blacklist the radeon (amdgpu) module:

```
echo "blacklist amdgpu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And then add the module to initramfs:

```
echo amdgpu | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```