# initramfs won't load radeon after blacklisting it in modprobe.d

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, initramfs

I followed the solution to this question: [pci-stub not claiming radeon card, only the audio device, radeon driver claiming graphics instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650707/pci-stub-not-claiming-radeon-card-only-the-audio-device-radeon-driver-claiming/675382#675382)

Now PCI_stub is claiming the devices (video and audio of my HD7970) properly, but as I have two AMD GPUs, I need the Radeon driver loaded, but this is not happening.

I can not find a solution as google is mostly pointing at the thread mentioned above and other threads are pretty old or for other linux distros.

Any idea what to do? I will happily provide any additional information needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got kind of a workaround going:

I added "modprobe radeon" to my rc.local file. This will take place after a few seconds while I am at the login screen, resets X and switches from low resolution to the normal monitor one. 
The only downside is, that it takes a few seconds to take place and it is recognized as a crash of X.org. Therefor I get an annoying apport pop-up window.

At least pci-stub binds correctly to the devices as both

```
dmesg | grep pci-stub
```

and

```
lshw -c video
```

show me.

I would still prefer a real solution, if there is any...